# Return to collectionView function after connectionDidFinishLoading

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

My question probably has a really obvious answer which I'm missing. I have an NSURLConnection like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

NSString *urlstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://127.0.0.1:8000/image/"];
NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest
                                    requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlstring]
                                    cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                    timeoutInterval:30.0];
[postRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
self.firstConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:postRequest delegate:self];

}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection
{
if (connection == _firstConnection){
    // Deal with the data
    [self getImages];
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}

-(void)getImages
{
NSError *error;
NSMutableArray* images= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_data options:0 error:&error];
NSUInteger arrayLength = [images count];


dressURLS = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSInteger i=0;i<arrayLength;i++)
{
    NSString *temp = [images[i] objectForKey:@"image"];
    [dressURLS addObject:temp];
}
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
UIImageView *dressImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];

NSString *clothesurl = dressURLS[i]; //i value????
NSString *url =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/%@",clothesurl];
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Update the UI
        dressImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    });
});

return cell;

}
```

The code is quite messy, I'm aware. This is how it works. `viewDidLoad` initializes the connection. It goes to `connectionDidFinishLoading` where `getImages` deals with the data which I had to manipulate and store in an array. Then I used the `reloadData` method to go to the Collection View which is where I run into all kinds of problems.

I need to access the elements of `dressURLS[i]` where i=0,1,2,3. But the looping is severely complicated by the fact that a. The collection view gets reloaded b. The asynchronous dispatch. I am unable to get `i` to loop from 0 to 3.

Any solutions to make this less complicated?

Comment: It looks like your NSURLConnection is getting the images, so what does getImages do?

Comment: @rdelmar NSURLConnection is creating the connection, but the NSJSONSerialization of the received data is happening in getImages.

Comment: So, after you call getImages, add the images you got to whatever array you use to populate the collection view, then call reloadData. Have you tried something like that?

Comment: @rdelmar I have but I've been running into all kinds of weird issues with null values being assigned. I have updated the code. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you implemented collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:? You need to have that method return the count of dressURLs. Then in cellForItemAtIndexPath, this line, NSString *clothesurl = dressURLS[i], should be NSString *clothesurl = dressURLS[indexPath.row].

Comment: @rdelmar I am in awe. After AGES struggling, that one line `NSString *clothesurl = dressURLS[indexPath.row]` fixed everything. It did not occur to me at all. If you post this as an answer, I would be more than happy to accept it. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection
{
if (connection == _firstConnection){
    // Deal with the data
    [self getImages];
    [collectionView reloaddata]; // or self.collectionView (for property)
}

}
```

"Discussion
Call this method to reload all of the items in the collection view. This causes the collection view to discard any currently visible items and redisplay them." - Apple

Comment: That really wasn't my question. There is nothing to reload or redisplay. Also there is no such thing as `[collectionView reload data];`

Comment: Yes there is https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/reloadData.

Comment: @Nikhita, what do you mean, there's nothing to reload or redisplay? You question says, "I would like to go back to the collectionView function to display the images in the collection view from the URLs I just received." Doesn't that require you to reload you collection view?

Answer (score 0):

You can the BOOL for the first time & for second time check the condition & display the images by reloading the Collection View.

Comment: Is this helpful to you??